# Segmentation fault happens when trying to free OCIEnv structure after failure of OCI environment setup with OCI_THREADED option

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

### Summary

Segmentation fault happens when trying to free OCIEnv structure after failure of OCI environment setup with OCI_THREADED option(failure due to eg. misconfigured NLS_LANG environment variable).

When OCIEnvCreate called *without* OCI_THREADED options the example code does not crash, it works as expected.

### Example code

```
#include <oci.h>;
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_connect(const char *username, const char *password, const char *sid)
{
  OCIEnv *env = NULL;
  OCIError *err = NULL;
  OCISvcCtx *svc = NULL;

  if ( OCIEnvCreate(&env,
                   OCI_THREADED,
                   (dvoid *)0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   0,
                   (size_t)0,
                   (dvoid **)0) )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to initialize environment\n");
    if ( env )
    {
      printf("env:[%p]\n", env);
      OCIHandleFree(env, OCI_HTYPE_ENV); // segfault.
    }
    return -1;
  }

  printf("env:[%p]\n", env);

  if ( OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *)env,
                      (dvoid **)&err,
                      OCI_HTYPE_ERROR,
                      (size_t)0,
                      (dvoid **)0) )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to alloc error handlers\n");
    goto error;
  }

  if ( OCIHandleAlloc((dvoid *) env,
                      (dvoid **) &svc,
                      OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX,
                      (size_t) 0,
                      (dvoid **)0) )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to allocate service handlers\n");
    goto error;
  }

  if ( OCILogon(env, 
                err, 
                &svc,
                (CONST OraText *) username,
                strlen(username),
                (CONST OraText *) password,
                strlen(password),
                sid,
                strlen(sid)
                ) )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "login failed\n");
    goto error;
  }
  printf("logged in\n");
  if ( OCILogoff (svc, err) )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "logoff failed\n");
    goto error;
  }
  printf("logged out\n");
error:
  if ( err )
    OCIHandleFree(err, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR);
  if ( svc )
    OCIHandleFree(svc, OCI_HTYPE_SVCCTX);
  if ( env )
    OCIHandleFree(env, OCI_HTYPE_ENV);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  return my_connect("test_user", "qqq123", "XE");
}
```

### Before run

```
export NLS_LANG=x
```

### Stack trace

The problem is that __pthread_mutex_destroy is called with a NULL-pointer.

```
#0    __pthread_mutex_destroy (mutex=0x0) at pthread_mutex_destroy.c:28
#1    0x00007ffff585e6e0 in sltsmxd () from /lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#2    0x00007ffff56a147c in kpufhndl0 () from /lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#3    0x00007ffff56a0185 in kpufhndl () from /lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#4    0x00007ffff567cac1 in OCIHandleFree () from /lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
#5    0x0000000000400a0c in my_connect (username=0x400dd1 "test_user", password=0x400dca       "qqq123", sid=0x400dc7 "XE") at test2.c:24
#6    0x0000000000400c27 in main () at test2.c:84
```

### Product details

```
Basic Lite Package Information

Thu Oct  4 13:00:49 UTC 2007

Client Shared Library 64-bit - 11.1.0.6.0

System name:    Linux
Release:        2.6.9-34.0.1.0.11.ELsmp
Version:        #1 SMP Mon Dec 4 22:20:39 UTC 2006
Machine:        x86_64
```

### OS details

```
Linux 3.2.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:28:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:       Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:           10.04
Codename:          lucid
```

### Question

At the moment I just do not free that memory area, but this is not a *good* solution.
What do you think, what would be the good solution?

Comment: FWIW, I get the same error from your code using the 11gR2 (11.2.0.3) 64-bit basic lite client on OEL 5.6, but not the basic client - which doesn't even get the 'unable to initialize environment' message, it logs in and out OK. The lite version gets errno 2, 'no such file or directory', presumably looking for something NLS-related that just doesn't exist. You'd think the non-lite one would complain about the invalid NLS_LANG somewhere though. Is using the non-lite instant client viable as a workaround?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I downloaded the basic client(Client Shared Library 64-bit - 11.2.0.3.0). The binary linked to libociei.so. When NLS_LANG is set to an invalid value, I got 'login failed' (but segfault gone :-) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it might be a bug in the 'Basic Lite' instant client, though I can't see anything relevant on MOS; but if so then in `OCIEnvCreate()`, not `OCIHandleFree()` as I think you suggest.

None of the example code I've seen tries to clean up the `OCIEnv` when it encounters a failure of `OCIEnvCreate()`; it seems to always just exit, including [Oracle's own example code](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/appdev.11203/e10646/oci16rel001.htm#sthref2433). It looks like that function is getting as far as creating the `OCIEnv` structure since you get a pointer to it, but presumably hasn't allocated the internals of that. Since it's in an indeterminate state, trying to clean it up will probably be a thankless task. So it seems like it ought to be OK to just not call `OCIHandleFree()`.

I was able to recreate the problem using the 11.2.0.3.0 Basic Lite client package for Linux x86-64 (from [TechNet downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)), under Oracle Enterprise Linux 5.6. When using the Basic (non-Lite) client package the problem was not seen - no memory fault, but also no 'unable to initialize environment' message, so the `OCIEnvCreate()` call succeeds. It does then fail to log in though, which is probably more reasonable anyway.

That suggests that you shouldn't expect the function to fail because of the `NLS_LANG` value - that part looks like a bug. If it does fail for some other reason then don't try to clean up. I can't see anything suggesting the SDK isn't expected to work with the Lite package, but you're forcing a failure and then trying to clean up beyond the norm, so the combination might not have been seen often before. Even without the clean-up triggering the memory fault, though, it looks like it's failing at the wrong point.

To get past the apparent bug and get the failure at the correct point, during login, you may need to switch to the Basic (non-Lite) client package.

Comment: I agree with you that the problem is not in OCIHandlerFree() .
( I think OCIEnvCreate shouldn't create that indeterminate state, just return with error and NULL-pointer. And I also think that NLS_LANG should not affect the login, it belongs to creating OCIEnv. )

Switching to the basic client package is an acceptible solution, thanks.